Replacing another person to myself to pull/push from git repo from an existing folder
A previous developer left a shared folder named "/opt/project_alpha" that he cloned from a github repo. Since he left he will not be able to work on this repo anymore so I will like to replace him as the new developer to do the same "push/pull" stuff from the same folder. How can I do to do this?

Which part is problematic to you? Credentials?

Is there a special config I need to do on the cloned folder to do this task? I do not want to destroy anything there.

One doesn't clone just a folder, but a repo (even if some config options allow to only recreate parts of the tree / history). Do you have access to the repo? Also check that you have access to existing remotes (namely here, the original github repo).

Yes, I do. Do you mean that anybody with the same credentials as the previous developer can do the "pull/push" stuff on the same cloned project placed in that folder? I thought that could depend on the the person that originally cloned that project for the first time.

Maybe try to start with a simple git fetch --dry-run to only check IF you would be able to fetch. This doesn't change anything in your local repo.

It sounds like you have two different users on a shared system.  /opt/project_alpha's contents probably belong to the original user.  So in addition to managing authentication to github (which typically follows the user) and configuration of git (user specific details of which may or may not be in /opt/project_alpha) , you'll also need to manage filesystem permissions.

"Do you mean that anybody with the same credentials as the previous developer can do the "pull/push…" Yes, so the first thing after someone resignation must be: revoke all her credentials in all internal networks, projects, services.
